# Can a python constructor be mocked without mocking other properties of the object?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, python-mock

Is it possible to mock a python constructor while continuing to use the production version other fields/functions on the same name? For example, given the production code:

```python
class MyClass:
    class SubClass:
        def __init__(self) -> None:
            print("\nreal sub init called")

        class SubSubClass:
            def __init__(self) -> None:
                print("\nreal sub sub init called")
```

and the following test code:

```python
class FakeSubClass:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        print("\nfake init called")


def test():
    MyClass.SubClass()
    MyClass.SubClass.SubSubClass()

    MyClass.SubClass = Mock(side_effect=FakeSubClass)

    MyClass.SubClass()
    MyClass.SubClass.SubSubClass()
```

we get the following output:

```
real sub init called

real sub sub init called

fake init called
```

Note that the last line `MyClass.SubClass.SubSubClass()` did not create a real SubSubClass because at this point it is an automatically created property of the SubClass mock.

My desired output is the following:

```
real sub init called

real sub sub init called

fake init called

real sub sub init called
```

In other words I want to mock ONLY the SubClass, but not SubSubClass. Things I have tried in place of the mocking line above (both of which do not work):

```
MyClass.SubClass.__init__ = Mock(side_effect=FakeSubClass.__init__)

MyClass.SubClass.__new__ = Mock(side_effect=FakeSubClass.__new__)
```

Note that I am aware of several ways the code could be refactored to avoid this issue but sadly the code cannot be refactored.

Comment: Those are not subclasses, not in the normal meaning of the term in the context of an object-oriented programming language; all you have are classes that are attributes of other classes. You’d normally want to avoid this. Why do you nest the classes here?

Comment: Next, when creating a unit test you generally would never mock only the `__init__`. You’d mock *everything that’s not the unit under test*. If the class you think you want to mock the `__init__` method of that unit, mock out things the `__init__` method calls, not the method itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also fake the class, the thing `MyClass.SubClass.SubSubClass()` wont work in your case is that `MyClass.SubClass` is a Mock dont have `SubSubClass` definition. Simply let `FakeSubClass` inherit it from MyClass.SubClass will solve the issue.

And you can easily patch `MyClass` to `FakeClass`, and you will have the right test object rather than real object.

```
from unittest.mock import Mock


class MyClass:
    class SubClass:
        def __init__(self) -> None:
            print("\nreal sub init called")

        class SubSubClass:
            def __init__(self) -> None:
                print("\nreal sub sub init called")


class FakeSubClass(MyClass.SubClass, Mock):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        print("\nfake init called")


class FakeClass:
    class SubClass(FakeSubClass):
        pass


def test():
    MyClass.SubClass()
    MyClass.SubClass.SubSubClass()

    MyClass.SubClass = Mock(side_effect=FakeSubClass)

    FakeClass.SubClass()
    FakeClass.SubClass.SubSubClass()
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree that ZhouQuan has a very good answer, as it will work for any method or variable on `MyClass.Subclass`. That said, here are some variations that may or may not be useful.

If for whatever reason the `FakeSubClass` can not be direct edited, or you only want to inherit `SubSubClass()` but nothing else, it can be changed in `test()` like this.

```
def test():
    MyClass.SubClass()
    MyClass.SubClass.SubSubClass()

    FakeSubClass.SubSubClass = MyClass.SubClass.SubSubClass()

    MyClass.SubClass = Mock(side_effect=FakeSubClass)

    MyClass.SubClass()
    MyClass.SubClass.SubSubClass()
```

I think it may be worth noting that `Mock` does accept a `wraps` argument, which could be used to get *similar* behavior, though it is not exactly what you asked for. Here is an example.

```
from unittest.mock import Mock

class MyClass:
    class SubClass:
        def __init__(self) -> None:
            print("\nreal sub init called")

        class SubSubClass:
            def __init__(self) -> None:
                print("\nreal sub sub init called")


class FakeSubClass:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        print("\nfake init called")

def test():
    MyClass.SubClass()
    MyClass.SubClass.SubSubClass()

    MyClass.SubClass = Mock(side_effect=FakeSubClass, wraps=MyClass.SubClass)

    MyClass.SubClass()
    MyClass.SubClass.SubSubClass()
```

This gives a different output.

```
real sub init called

real sub sub init called

fake init called # A call to MyClass.SubClass() causes both real and fake inits.

real sub init called # Same MyClass.SubClass() call.

real sub sub init called # But now the SubSubClass() does resolve correctly.
```